# mvc errors in strange dlls

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, dll

I am using Visual Studio Enterprise 2015 update 3, I get this error:

```
An exception of type 'System.NullReferenceException' occurred in App_Web_kiedumwa.dll in my MVC 5 c# application.
```

I have no idea what or where **App_Web_kiedumwa.dll** I am not concerned about the **NullReferenceException** but about this dll, I searched the solution and all drives on my computer and could not find it.  When I tried the application again I got different dll name with the same exception.  I even developed another project and duplicated the error; I got another dll name.

Just to be on the safe side, is this is normal?

Comment: I cant even seem to find this DLL via google. What is the name of your application?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is a dynamically generated assembly by the ASP.NET runtime when it compiled your views. So basically you should not be surprised about the name of the assembly - that's expected.

> Just to be on the safe side, is this is normal?

Yes, this is an absolutely normal dynamic assembly.

Comment: Thank you Darin, you have always been great help.